# How to get a list of all processes including DLLs they use using Process Monitor?

Tags: process

Ctrl-A allows to save a report only for a single executable.
Thanks

Comment: Could you be more descriptive?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Sysinternals command-line tool [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx):

```
C:\>handle .dll

Handle v3.31
Copyright (C) 1997-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

System             pid: 4       6D8: C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
System             pid: 4       6F0: C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always write your own code to do it.  [This example from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701(VS.85).aspx) shows you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the built in commands at the command line and export it to a file, like the following `tasklist /M > ModulesForProcesses.txt`?